# When I direct wire my LED bulbs to 120 V. they only flash in when the wires are touched

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

These are Utilitech T8 LED bulbs. The box says they work with an electronic ballast. Will they work direct wire 120V also? I tested them before installation and they only light for a millisecond when I touch wire to the pins.

Comment: If the instructions say that they work with electronic ballasts and don't mention direct-wire, then you shouldn't expect them to work with direct wire.

Answer (score 5):

Attempting to use a ballast-type LED replacement that does not say "or direct wire" as well; as a direct-wire device will most likely just leave you with a device that doesn't work at all.

If they've done a better than average job perhaps it will still work on a ballast, but I'd fully expect that you may already have fried it by applying the wrong voltage to it.

Comment: Yes, I would expect applying mains voltage to any electronic device not designed for mains voltage to rapidly let the magic smoke escape. Without said magic smoke, electronic devices do not work.

Comment: OK thanks, any idea what ballast I should buy? I have more bulbs.

Comment: Electronic, T8, for the same number of bulbs as your fixtures.

Comment: @Bert don't buy any ballast. Toss those LEDs and buy direct-wire LEDs.  Utilitech is cheap stuff and not worth the price of a ballast.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 distinct types of LED replacement "tube".

- **Plug-n-Play**: you MUST retain the original ballast.
- **Direct-wire, double-ended**: Ballast is bypassed. Hot goes to the lampholders at one end of the fixture.  Neutral goes to the lampholders at the other end of the fixture.
- **Universal**: A dual-mode LED that will work both of the above ways.
- **Direct-wire, single-ended**: Ballast is bypassed. At one end of the fixture, nothing is connected. At the other end, both hot and neutral connect to the same lampholder. (This is not good, and is falling out of favor).

What you paid for is plug-n-play. "Universal" is an extra-cost feature, because it lets you stock one thing and slap them in everywhere, and go back and bypass the ballast only when the ballast fails.   You didn't pay extra for that ability, so you didn't get it.

It sounds to me like you did your test as if "single-ended". That only works on direct-wire, single-ended LEDs.

Since your fixture is already ballast-bypass, I would wire it to be "double-ended" and then buy "universal" or "direct-wire, double-ended" tubes.

Utilitech is a cheap brand and a couple of tubes aren't worth buying a ballast for.  You'll spend more on ballasts than you would on some equally cheap (Feit Electric, Commercial Electric) direct-wire double-ended LEDs.

I am the biggest advocate of real fluorescent tubes you'll ever find.  You already see why, since this is the second set of LED "tubes" in this fixture. They don't last near as long as they claim.  But no in your case, with the ballast already gone, I wouldn't fool around with it. Just get double-ended direct-wire LED "tubes". It helps to buy quality.